# configuring https://yourdomain.com on Google Appengine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, ssl, dns, subdomain

I recently started using SSL on my appengine app (i.e. uploaded my certs). I got

https://www.mydomain.com to work, but
https://mydomain.com does not work (doesn't resolve in the browser).

I already have http://mydomain.com redirecting to http://www.mydomain.com but ideally that redirects to https. (i'd like everything to redirect to https and www).

Anyone know how to set this up?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you're outlining two (possibly) separate issues here, *but please correct me if I don't fully understand your issue*:

1. URLS with `https://` (as opposed to `http://`) are not working
2. Specifically, you want `http://streak.com` to redirect to `https://www.streak.com` and, in general, you want **all** `http://` links to redirect to their secure (`https://`) counterparts with the www subdomain; e.g. `http://streak.com/user/login` should redirect to `https://www.streak.com/user/login`

#### https:// is not working

It's likely that you've already visited [SSL for a Custom Domain - Google App Engine — Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/ssl), but it's possible that you may have overlooked a few points that would cause SSL URLs not to function as intended:

Under the **Activating** heading:

> You must have an App Engine application with billing enabled that has cleared at least one billing charge; use this application when enabling SSL

Also, under the **Uploading and Configuring Certificate** heading and **To configure a certificate** *after you have uploaded it* subheading:

> Work with your DNS provider to update CNAME records. For each domain in the assigned URLs, change the CNAME record to the CNAME given in the "CNAME to" field.

Finally, make sure that your application's web.xml file is configured to correctly handle secure URLs: [The Deployment Descriptor: web.xml - Google App Engine — Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/webxml#Secure_URLs)

#### Always Redirect to `https://www.`

This should be trivial to implement within your application. See [The Java Servlet Environment - Google App Engine — Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/runtime#Requests_and_Domains) or the documentation for the framework that you're using.

Good luck!

Comment: Actually I have done most of this (thats how I got https://www.mydomain.com to work). The one that isn't working is http://mydomain.com. Is that a CNAME issue or something that needs to be setup in appengine/google apps?

Comment: "h t t p s://mydomain.com" does NOT work, "h t t p://mydomain.com" DOES work. (had to add spaces so stacoverflow doesn't auto parse

Comment: OK, so if http://www... works, and https://www works, but the naked domain versions of those does not then yes, you will need to set up a CNAME that directs naked domain requests to the www subdomain. Your nameserver probably has instructions to do this. Note: CNAME does not include HTTP or HTTPS, so you need to add (as mentioned in my answer) code to you app to redirect from non-secure to a secure requests.

Comment: I have a CNAME, thats how I got h t t p://mydoma.... to work. Do I need a seperate CNAME for https?